# How to access ec2 instance that is not associated with key pair

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, key-pair

I have an ec2 instance that was spun up automatically through autoscale.  It doesn't have a key pair associated with it.  Can I assign my existing key to it?  If not how do I log into the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are out of luck if you want to SSH in at this point. Key needs to be assigned as part of *as-create-launch-config* command.

Comment: How do I associate the key in the launch config?

Comment: use the *-key* option on *as-create-launch-config*